# How do I structure a table view to load halfway down a view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to make my UITableView load covering half of the window with a background view that starts visible, and as the window scrolls, is gradually covered by the table's cells.

Initially, I want to style is like so:

[image: Imgur]

As the user scrolls, the cells will cover the background element. [image: Imgur]

The only way I could think to accomplish this would be to put the background element behind (and outside) a ScrollView (which is sized to fit over the background element and has a transparent background), put the TableView inside the ScrollView, and set the load coordinates to start the table far enough down.  Is there a better way to accomplish my desired design?

I would prefer to avoid this layout because I would like to be able to easily add more cells dynamically as the user scrolls, ideally without having to deal with resizing the ScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a view inside table view just above the table view cell and make its height whatever you want space in table view and make a outlet of that view. Then in view did load assign the view as table header view like this.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
```

This will be displayed exactly like you given and when user scrolls it will show the below cells and when you want you can change the frame of the header view and your header become invisible. You can do it whenever you want i mean if you want to change height on scrolling or if you want to change on adding more cells.

Comment: Worked like a charm -- much better than my half-solution.  Thank you!